# Run a command in a file on another text file

Tags: linux

I have a filter command saved in a file (say `filter.txt`). The command could be something similar to following

```
grep "PASS"
```

Then I also have a output file of a testcase (say `output.log`). I want to us the filter command saved in the `filter.txt` file on the `output.log`.

I was looking for something like

```
cat output.log | `cat filter.txt`
```

But seems like it does not work. Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
cat output.log | bash filter.txt
```

You need some program (like bash) that interprets the lines in `filter.txt` as commands to be executed.